Partially shared home: dual boot, same /home partition, one user per OS, same UIDs for perms, but different home dirs
Here is a general outline of what I want to achieve, given that I am the only user of my computer:

Dual boot with 2 Linux OS
Easily share (read/write, probably no execute) some of the data accessed between the two OS.

I am aware of the general pitfalls of mounting the very same /home/<user>, even when the two "users" have the same UID for both OSes. Hence, the fact that I only want to share "some" data is not because some data should be hidden/inaccessible, it is simply to avoidf conflicts, and so I don't want to share everything at once.
Is there any pitfall to the following solution:

Threee partitions, are root-1, root-2, shared-home
Mount shared-home both to /root-1/home and /root-2/home (i.e., both /root-1/etc/fstab and /root-2/etc/fstab specifically mount the shared partition to /home/)
In OS1, set <user>'s UID to e.g. 1000, and its home directory to /home/user-1
In OS2, also set <user>'s UID to 1000, but set the home directory to /home/user-2

Assuming commons GID too (and maybe a bit more ? I am not completely sure what would need to be synchronized across the two OSes for both "users" in this setting ...), this should allow me to easily access all the files (in fact, as far as both OSes are concerned, there would only be a single user anyway, as permissions will be the same, given the common UID/GID), but still have separate home directories, and so everything related to e.g. config files would be kept separate -- excepting some potential symlinks between the two.
Other solutions:

Don't bother with separate home: this might lead to conflict with software versions, config files, etc
Have two actual separate users (different UIDs in the two OSes), and another folder symlinked/mounted separately: then, sharing files becomes a bit tedious, as permissions need to be set up more carefully.

TL;DR: any pitfall to having a (Linux) dual-boot (say OS1 and OS2), with a shared /home/ partition, with two folders /home/user1 (home directory of $USER in OS1) and /home/user2 (home directory of $USER in OS2), but using the same UID/GID for both users so as to effectively be able to have synchronized permissions (and so, shared data) but separate home directories ?

It's always preferable to have an independent shared data partition. /home stores all user settings, not only personal files. Those settings differ and can (actually will) conflict. Once upon a time I tried to reuse a /home partition from a Mint installation to a new Ubuntu installation and it was a mess. In this case was one after the other and one is based on the other! Now imagine one overwriting the other's settings over and over.

Unless I misunderstand something: basically, /home only contains subdirectories, typically one per user (its home dir ...), and the "user settings" that you talk about /will/ belong to different subdirectories, provided the users have different home dirs (and therefore, won't conflict). So /home/user1/ and /home/user2/ should not conflict, if accessed by different OSes, as configs/settings will be stored in the correct (for the OS) user home dir. No ?

Just note that the user in both installation would be able to access both home ditectories.

@TomYan That is part of the point, yes, so that I can share everything easily, while keeping everything separate in a sense, as each OS will use a different value of $HOME for a user with the same UID. The question was precisely whether having this kind of "double home directory for a single user" could be dangerous/have unexpected side effects.

@Numbra well, it can't exactly have "double home", especially if you literally use a directory name that is not (just) username in both cases. In other words, the only "danger" I could think of is, some silly thing tries to form the HOME to use by simply concatenating /home/ with username.  Also, say the username user_A is used in both installations but the two users have different UID, it might result in you having confusion...
